# media center software for dual-audio VCD recommendation

Tags: media-center, kodi, mediaportal

I already have a large collection of Karaoke VCD, they are basically mpeg movies with dual audio track.  ie, the left audio channel has the music only, and right channel has music + vocal.  In karaoke, one would normally select the left channel to be play thur both speaker.

I'm aware of Media center software like `xbmc` or `mediaportal`, but never played with them. I tried searching for their website, but can't for sure whether it can select a single audio around like this or not.  I found a post that xbmc didn't support this, but it was back in 2004.

Does anyone have any recommendation / experience on an easy to use software for this? open to either Win or Linux options.

UPDATED:  Looks like XBMC won't work since it's no longer using mplayer:
http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?t=74451
Are there any alternatives that are easy to operate?  Imagine your grandpa & grandma using it... so not very computer savy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up using VLC.   `audio > audio channels > choose left or right`

Answer (score 1):

[**XBMC**](http://xbmc.org/download/) now supports selection of left or right channel audio stream for video playback. According to [XBMC Features and Supported Formats/Codecs](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=XBMC_Features_and_Supported_Formats/Codecs#Features_available_for_video_playback:) page,

> - Switch between multiple audio streams/tracks
> - Left, Right, Mono and Stereo channel selection available for all
>     two channel audio-streams

Comment: Any idea on where to change the channel selection?  Can it be bind to a particular key?